# how to pass links to fread in php?

Tags: php, xml, fread

I have a 500 link to xml files (online files) I want to pass those files to a function that read the content of these files, parse them and then store them in my database (mysql).
I use this function to get the links:

```
function get_links()
{
    $user_file = @fopen("./fullsoccer.TXT", "r");
    if ($user_file) 
    {
        while (!feof($user_file)) 
        {
            $lines[] = fgets($user_file, 4096);
        }
        fclose($user_file);
    }
    return $lines;
}
```

then I use this function to read each link content and parse it :

```
function doParse($parser_object) {
    $links=get_links();
    $i=0;
    while(!empty($links[$i]))
    {
        if (!($fp = fopen($links[$i], "r")));
        {
            //loop through data
            while ($data = fread($fp, 4096)) {
                //parse the fragment
                xml_parse($parser_object, $data, feof($fp));
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

The links are returned successfully (I print them in the "doParse" function) but the problem is :
the "doParse" function just parse the file of the last link.
I want to know why the function parse just the file of the last link and leave the whole previous 499 files ? is it fopen problem ?? does it able of reading more than 1 file?

Comment: why dont use use $links=file("./fullsoccer.TXT"); also instead of fopen use file_get_contents instead of while use foreach this code can be simplifed. If you use opening files via network maybe you should consider CURL?

Comment: how can curl get the file content as xml

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$links=get_links();
```

to

```
$links=file("./fullsoccer.TXT");
```

[File](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function is used to read file contents into array where array item is a line.

you can use foreach instead of while loop. To get content of link you may use [file_get_contents();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) but the best way is to use CURL because server may have some security issues when you want to get the data just by fopen

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

I have found curl example of how to download data from link

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download

Comment: I used file instead of get links() and foreach instead of while but I want to know if I used curl how to get the file data as xml